# How to properly write unit tests for a logout service using jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm still new to unit tests so I wonder if anyone help me with this small task.
I'm using angular 8 with jasmine.

This is my service for the logout:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogoutService {
    logout() {
        const {protocol, hostname, port: locationPort} = window.location;
        const port = locationPort ? `:${locationPort}` : '';
        window.location.href =
                `/oauth/logout?redirect=${protocol}//${hostname}${port}`;
    }
}
```

This is my test that I'm trying:

```js
import { LogoutService } from './logout.service';

describe('LogoutService', () => {
    let service;
    beforeEach(() => {
        service = new LogoutService();
    });
    it('should run #logout()', async () => {
        let path = '/oauth/logout?redirect'
        service.logout();
        expect(window.location.href).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(path))

    });
});
```

So far I'm trying to test if windows location has the protocol & the hostname & the port.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The test looks good. Do you see any errors?

Comment: I can see this error :  Error: You must provide an object to objectContaining, not '/oauth/logout?redirect'.at <Jasmine> at http://localhost:9879/_karma_webpack_/src/app/service/logout/logout.service.spec.ts:11:34 at <Jasmine>

It's normal since I'm providing a string inside objectContaining and I need to provide an object instead.

Comment: Yes because you're asserting on a string. Try `expect(window.location.href).toContain(path);`

Comment: The test failed, I guess because window.location.href doesn't contain /oauth/logout ... hmmm

Comment: Try `console.log(window.location.href)` right after `service.logout()` and see what it gives you.

Comment: it gives me this:
http://localhost:9879/context.html
if I run it I got this:
http://localhost:9879/oauth/logout?redirect=http://localhost:9879

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you are using the wrong function: according to official documentation, [jasmine.objectContaining](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Partial_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.objectContaining%3C/code%3E) deals not with strings but with jsons. [toContain](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction#section-Included_Matchers) would be a better option in your case.

Second, you aim at testing if window.location contains data such as protocol etc. So checking against '/oauth/logout?redirect' (your path variable) is not the solution.

Third, your service design states that window.location functions both as input (external dependency to be more accurate) and as output to test, plus you seem to have global variable locationPort as another input. In order to achieve a useful test, you should control your inputs (controlling inputs can simply mean reassigning window.location, but this can be problematic; this issue can be addressed, however, by redesigning logout method).

That being said, you may try something like this:

```js
logout(wl: any) {
  const {protocol, hostname, port: locationPort} = wl;
  const port = locationPort ? `:${locationPort}` : '';
  return `/oauth/logout?redirect=${protocol}//${hostname}${port}`;
}
it('should run #logout()', async () => {
  const wl = { ...window.location, protocol: 'some-protocol', hostname: 'some-hostname' };
  locationPort = 4200;
  const href = service.logout(wl);
  expect(href).toContain('some-protocol');
  expect(href).toContain('some-hostname');
  expect(href).toContain('4200');
  // or
  // expect(href).toContain(`some-protocol//some-hostname:4200`);
});
```

(of course, in your application you would have to assign logout method's return value into window.location.href)

This change I've made to logout method is more than a technical change; it reflects how unit tests make us rethink of our code design.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get this error: (I also tried ``)
`Type '{ protocol: string; hostname: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Location': ancestorOrigins, hash, host, href, and 7 more.`